# After installation successful of Magento 2.2.7 invalid template file error is coming

Tags: magento2.2.7, invalid-template, exception-error

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'require.js'

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 'require.js'
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php(300): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('C:/xampp/htdocs...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Result\Page.php(248): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Result\Layout.php(170): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\generated\code\Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(139): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(257): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#9 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Windows uses "\" as separator, the array "directories" contains entries with "/" as separator, so the check will always fail.**

So you need to fix this by replacing the separator in core file:

```
Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator
```

function isPathInDirectories   replace below code in isPathInDirectories function

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```